# Javascript: Convert HTML Input Form Names/Values to object graph (MeteorJS)

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript

I have a (really large) form in a MeteorJS controller. I have a couple hundred inputs that have names e.g. "sheetProperties.X.Y" "sheetProperties.SubForm1.FavoriteColor", etc.

I don't want to declare all of the possible inputs in the form because this will become a nightmare to maintain as they change often, and there are LOTS.

To make it work, I've put something like this in my controller:

#### Controller:

```
#this only works on object without any subproperties..
props = {}
for element in event.target
  if element.tagName == "INPUT"            
    if name.startsWith "sheetProperties"
      props[name] = element.value
```

What I want to do, is take the name and turn it into an object reference.

I started this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/c463acyu/2/
The goal is to take a long name "sheetProperties.something.somethignElse" and turn this into a proper object with e.g.

#### Desired Object Graph:

```
sheetProperties:
  something:
    somethingElse: "Value goes here"
```

#### Sample Code:

```
name = "foo.bar.baz"
value = "42"



names = name.split '.'
console.log names
objGraph = {}
currentObj = objGraph
for name in names  
    lastObj = currentObj
    currentObj = currentObj[name] ?= {}    

lastObj[name] = value

console.log(objGraph)
```

### Is the above fiddle safe? How can it be made so? Is there a better way?

Comment: You should definitely use simple-schema (https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) and autoform (https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform), it will save you hours of coding :)

Comment: I actually am using collection2 and have aldeed:autoform -- I had a large set of AngularJS template already made and this will save me alot of time in the long run. Good advice, though!